# How to make the Delete key work in micro (text editor) when this is running under st terminal (from bspwm)?

Tags: command-line, text-editor, keys

How to make the Delete key work in the [Micro](https://micro-editor.github.io/) text editor, when this is running under st terminal (from bspwm)?

When I press the Delete key, this sequence appears: "[P".

I have tried changing the TERM and COLORTERM variables, as well as putting "set enable-keypad on" on /etc/inputrc.  But none of these worked. St terminal has st-256color in the TERM environment variable opposed to xterm-256color which is what several others terminals do.

I'm currently using Lubuntu 18.04 LTS. BTW: I'm not using Bspwm, but Lxde instead. I just mentioned Bspwm because it is more closely related with st terminal.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by editing the file:

**~/.config/micro/bindings.json**

Replace the line `"Delete": "Delete",` 
with this: `"\u001b[P": "Delete",`

And append this line at the end of the list:

`"\u001b[4h": "ToggleOverwriteMode"` (this will fix the Insert key as well). Just remember to put a comma (,) at the end of the line just before this one.